# Реинициализация jQuery плагина

Tags: jquery, javascript, select

Как инициализировать плагин JQuery select2  после его подгрузки через ajax?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    success: function(data){
       //Тут ваш код
       $(selector).select2();
    }    
})
```

Возможно пригодится [jQuery.ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)

Comment: К сожалению, данный метод не работает..

$(".editindoc").live("click", function() {

var editdocId = $(this).attr("id");

 $.ajax({'type':'POST','data':{'id':editdocId},'url':'myurl','cache':false,
 dataType : "html", success: function (html) { 

 $("#EditIncoming").html(html);
 $("#Paymants_DocType").select2(); 
 }
    });
});

Появляется следующая ошибка " undefined' is not a function (evaluating...'